# Configuring protractor with cucumber in Intellij

Tags: intellij-idea, protractor, cucumber, cucumberjs

I am trying to configure Protractor with Cucumber in Intellij But I have an error when I run the test with the current configuration.

[run configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X7cB9.png)

I am receiving the error bellow

```
       Testing started at 18:30 ...
   /usr/local/bin/node /Users/marianojover/IdeaProjects/AutomationTest_PRO/node_modules/cucumber/bin/cucumber /Users/marianojover/IdeaProjects/AutomationTest_PRO/features/test.feature --format "../../../Library/Application Support/IntelliJIdea2018.1/CucumberJavaScript/lib/cucumberjs_formatter_v2.js" --format-options "{\"cucumberLibPath\": \"/Users/marianojover/IdeaProjects/AutomationTest_PRO/node_modules/cucumber/lib\"}" --require /Users/marianojover/IdeaProjects/AutomationTest_PRO/features
   internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:583
   throw err;
   ^

   Error: Cannot find module '/Users/marianojover/IdeaProjects/AutomationTest_PRO/node_modules/cucumber/bin/cucumber'
   at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:581:15)
   at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:507:25)
   at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:742:12)
   at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:236:19)
   at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:560:3)

   Process finished with exit code 1
```

The error is not giving information that I can consider useful in order to solve the problem.

Comment: Is the module it is complaining about in that directory? If not, why is it being told to look in that directory? Where is it _supposed_ to be found?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running Cucumber.js 4.x is not currently supported, please follow [WEB-33787](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-33787) for updates

Comment: Thanks for replying. Could you please check the link because is returning a 404.

Comment: The message is 
404: Nope, can't find it!
Despite our best efforts, there's nothing here to show you with the URL you requested. Most likely the URL is invalid or you don't have permissions to access the page.

Apparently it is related to permissions

Comment: Ups... A permissions issue indeed. I've changed the ticket visibility, please try again

Comment: :( no luckies. Same message

Comment: please try once more - I've made it visible to everybody

Comment: Now I can see it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you have cucumber added to the node_modules folder which is in your project directory. I hope it is there by looking at the paths in your run configuration.

You can also add cucumber cli path to "Cucumber.js arguments" in your run configuration. The path to add is ./node_modules/.bin/cucumber-js (should be modified based on your directory structure). Please see https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-js/blob/master/docs/cli.md

If the above does not work then you can also use node.js runner to run your protractor test. Just add a new run configuration and add node.js and then add the parameters in  configuration tab of the runner, some are given below -

Working Directory -> This will be the path to your project.

Javascript File -> node_modules\protractor\built\cli.js

Application Paramters -> --specs=<*path to your feature file*><*space*><*path to your protractor.conf.js*>